# pip2 insists on using local python path

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

Earlier I installed `pyenv` and installed python2.7 and python3.4 but I deactivated it from `.bashrc`

I tried to install `virtualenv` in the following way

```
# Install virtual environment
sudo pip2 install virtualenv virtualenvwrapper
echo "# Virtual Environment Wrapper" >> ~/.bashrc
echo "source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh" >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc

############ For Python 2 ############
# create virtual environment
mkvirtualenv facecourse-py2 -p python2
```

at the final stage I got some errors like

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pkg_resources (from versions: )
```

Then I did `pip install --upgrade setuptools` as suggested by Q/A in the net.

After then I began to get

```
    /home/kenn/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/packaging/requirements.py", line 59, in <module>
MARKER_EXPR = originalTextFor(MARKER_EXPR())("marker")
```

errors when I attempt to install packages with `pip2` though `pip` works OK. 
I also tried exporting python path like

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

but the result's not changed.

I noticed that error resulted from parse error in the latest version of the `setuptools` so I tried

```
sudo pip install setuptools==33.1.1
```

it downgraded the version of the `setuptools` but it didn't resolve the problem since it downgraded the package in `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages`

I activated `pyenv` switched to python2.7 which uses `/home/kenn/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/` path then ran

```
sudo pip install setuptools==33.1.1
```

I deactivated `pyenv` again and switched to system python2.7 and problem gone.

But `pip2` keeps loading local libraries in `/home/kenn/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/`

Why?

Comment: ~/.local is enabled by default (for `pip install --user`).  You could disable it using -s or PYTHONNOUSERSITE. See https://docs.python.org/2/library/site.html#site.USER_SITE). There are other issues (avoid `sudo pip` in general and installing python to /usr/local in particular)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Thank you for the explanation. As I pointed out in my question `pip` works well but `pip2` acts up. Now that you clarified the point would you post it as an answer? Users may benefit from it.

Comment: both pip and pip2 use `~/.local` (as well as any other `python` script). I don't know what to answer here. As I said, there are several issues in the question (mixing users, system/pyvenv python executables, having non-emtpy PYTHONPATH + yet another moving part: active/inactive virtualenv). You could update your question and mention explicitly what the original task was (focus the quesiton on a single problem) and then (only then) describe the unsuccessful attempts (that use `sudo pip`, `export PYTHONPATH`, etc).